# SqlDataReader OpenAsync hangs application

Tags: c#, async-await, sqldatareader

I'm writing simple class which will connect to SQL DB and get data from it.

I would like to make it async, but I've got some problem with async programming.

Code:

```
public async Task<ICommand> ExecuteAsync(SqlConnection connection)
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(Query);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = connection;

    if(connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        await connection.OpenAsync();

    using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
    {
        if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)
        {

            while (await sqlDataReader.ReadAsync())
            {
                Entry = new Entry();
                Entry.ID = (int) sqlDataReader["ID"];
                Entry.User = (string) sqlDataReader["UserName"];
                object o = sqlDataReader["EntryType"];
                Entry.EntryType = o.Equals("Enter") ? EntryType.Enter : EntryType.Leave;
                Entry.DateTime = (DateTime) sqlDataReader["EntryDate"];

            }
        }
    }
```

With this code, debugger always stop executing after OpenAsync() method. It does not hit next statement.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Regards

**--EDIT--**
I am running it on desktop right now(Simple unit test)
I have added try-catch to handle exceptions.

My minimal sample:

ExecuteAsync method:

```
public async Task<ICommand> ExecuteAsync(SqlConnection connection)
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(Query);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = connection;

    if(connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)
        {

            while (await sqlDataReader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                Entry = new Entry();
                Entry.ID = (int) sqlDataReader["ID"];
```

//                        Entry.User = (string) sqlDataReader["UserName"];
//                        object o = sqlDataReader["EntryType"];
//                        Entry.EntryType = o.Equals("Enter") ? EntryType.Enter : EntryType.Leave;
//                        Entry.DateTime = (DateTime) sqlDataReader["EntryDate"];
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

Invoking of this method:

```
    public void ExecuteCommandAsync(ICommand command, ReadFinished continueWith)
    {
        if(continueWith == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("Parameter 'continueWith' cannot be null");
        command.ExecuteAsync(_connection).ContinueWith(task => continueWith(task.Result)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

My test case:

```
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        TimeTableDBConnector.DbConnector connector = new DbConnector(null);
        var getEntryByIDCommand = new GetEntryByIDCommand(1);
        ICommand result;
        try
        {
            connector.ExecuteCommandAsync(getEntryByIDCommand, ContinueWith );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }


    }

    private void ContinueWith(ICommand command)
    {
        GetEntryCommand cmd = (GetEntryCommand) command;
    }
```

Comment: This snippet looks fine. Does the connection work when you use `connection.Open()` instead of `connection.OpenAsync()`? Are you doing this in a desktop application, or in a service (or a web application)? Can you whittle this down to a minimal *complete* sample application that displays this behaviour? Is it possible that an exception got thrown and you haven't properly handled that?

Comment: See my edit with more code. Additionally, same code, without Async works perfectly

Comment: @Tomasz, removed my answer now that more details have been published. Unit tests don't use `SynchronizationContext`, so my answer did not apply.

Comment: Try calling it like this - `command.ExecuteAsync(...).Wait()`. You can't just fire and forget an asynchronous task in a unit test - most likely, as soon as you exit the `TestMethod1`, the test is stopped. You have to block *somewhere* until you get the asynchronous response.

Comment: Thanks, Wait methot helped

Comment: @Tomasz, now that you have the `Wait` method in the chain if you remove the `ConfigureAwait` inside your `ExecuteAsync` and go running your code as part of an application which uses a `SynchronizationContext` (i.e. Windows Forms, WPF), you will run into the *exact* problem I described earlier. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Most testing frameworks support asynchronous tests so if you change your `ExecuteCommandAsync` method to return `Task` you should be able to mark your test as `async` and `await` the result of `ExecuteCommandAsync`. Give this a try:

```
async void TestMethod1()
{
    TimeTableDBConnector.DbConnector connector = new DbConnector(null);
    var getEntryByIDCommand = new GetEntryByIDCommand(1);
    ICommand result;
    try
    {
        await connector.ExecuteCommandAsync(getEntryByIDCommand, ContinueWith );
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```